# A basic question on boundedness of Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to prove that Riemann integrable implies function is bounded by contradiction. Suppose function is not bounded, then I want to find an $\epsilon$ such that for all partition $P$ there exist a set of sample points $T$ such that $|R(f,P,T) - I| \geq \epsilon$ for any given $I$. How to find those sample points and $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Because your working over _all_ partitions, which means you have to include the partition including the point(s) where your function is/are unbounded.

Comment: You can always refine to a partition that has the properties you want.

Comment: Many authors require a function be bounded as a criterion for Riemann integrability.  If a function is not bounded, its integral is "improper."

Answer (score 1):

You find the sample points, because Riemann convergence means that for *all* partitions of width less than $\|P\|$, the integral must coonverge. This means you must include in your sum the point(s) where $f$ is unbounded, so that your sum is not indefinitely small.